# Angular upgrade from 5 to 6 causing errors

Tags: angular, spring-mvc, angular-cli

I have a separate spring mvc webapp, and a separate angular 5 - angular cli application, and their integration was working fine.

However, after doing angular 6 upgrade,and also angular cli upgrade from 1.5.2 to 6, the packages are running fine independently, but when I tried interacting with the angular application from the webapp, it is showing errors.

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)
>
> for styles.js:1 , main.js:1, vendor.js:1, runtime.js:1, polyfills.js:1
>   .

I have been able to hit the `index.html` page of the angular application successfully, but from there on wards error is happening. Can anyone guide what changes in configuration do I need to make to integrate the webapp with angular application.

Answer (score 1):

Remove/delete the `/node_modules` folder/directory by

`rm -rf /node_modules`

and run

`npm install`.

Hope it helps..!!